# Passing bool from one form to another (not working)

Tags: c#, boolean

I am in the middle of a project and I am trying to pass a bool from one Form to another but any time i do so it does not work.

Form 1

```
public bool test = false;
private void bluelineToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Background_Mainframe_Blueline;
    test = true;
}
```

Form 2

```
private void AboutWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Mainframe main = new Mainframe();

    if (main.test == true) //reads test as false rather then true.
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Background_About_Blueline;
    }
}
```

When the second form loads it is to read the bool as true but it reads as false.

Am i reading the bool wrong?

Can someone please help.

Comment: Was it true when the form loaded? It seems like you only set test to true when the button is pressed, which might be after the form is loaded.

Also, that's not how that works. If Form2 is contained in Form1, it won't be aware of Form1's existence, like any other object in C#. If you really need your second form to get data from the first form, you can have Form1 call methods on Form2 that mutate data within it.

Comment: it's because you're creating a new Main form, which sets the variables back to their default values, rather than referencing the Main form you've already created.  Create a new class file and put the bool variable in that new class and use that in both forms.

Comment: Why would the About window create a new Mainframe?  I suspect you're doing that just to have an object to access, but in reality you need to access an existing instance of Mainframe.

Comment: @sous2817 I will do that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's true. When `Form2` Loads, the `main` form initializes. In the initialization `main.test` is `False`. You have to click `bluelineToolStripMenuItem` of `main` form to set `main.test` to `True`. But the if condition checks just after the initialization of `main` form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass along a reference to the parent form when you create the child form, not instantiate a new one from within the child.

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by creating a new public class called Variables.cs and then adding the variables to the class and calling them in other classes.

Example:

Variables.cs

```
public class Variables
{
    public static bool test = false;
}
```

Form1

```
private void bluelineToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Variables.test = true;
}
```